# Sorting - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' , Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort an excel I got the below error:

```
File "D:\Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4725, in sort_values
    na_position=na_position)
  File "D:\Projects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py", line 273, in nargsort
    indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I tried with the below lines of code, How can I solve this issue.

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('file1.xlsx')
    df = excel_file.parse('Sheet1')
    df = df.sort_values(by=['Name'], ascending=True)

    writer = ExcelWriter('File2.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward... somewhere in your xlsx you have an int where you expect there to be strings or vice versa. Check your data.

Comment: Can you show the full error traceback so we can see which code caused it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like your 'Name' column has mixed data types - some strings and some integers. You can treat the integers as strings by converting the column to type string before doing the sort:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(str)
df.sort_values(by='Name', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

That said, it doesn't sound like a column called 'Name' should have integers in it, so I'd probably recommend examining your data more closely before proceeding with this solution.